# Is it possible to select an Action with AttributeRouting in .NET MVC based on the Media Type of the Accept header?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, .net-4.5, attributerouting

I want to select an Action of my Controller based on the Media Type requested in the Accept header.

For example, I have a resource called a subject. Its assigned route is:

> GET /subjects/{subjectId:int}

Normally, the browser is requesting `text/html`, which is fine. The default Media Formatter handles this great.

Now, I have custom logic I want to perform when this same route is accessed with an accept header specifying `application/pdf` as the accepted Media Type.

I could create a custom Media Formatter, but, to my understanding, this would mean that any route that is requested with the Accept header set to `application/pdf` would also run through this Media Formatter. This is unacceptable.

In Java, there is an annotation called [`@Produces`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gipxf/index.html):

> The @Produces annotation is used to specify the MIME media types or
>   representations a resource can produce and send back to the client. If
>   @Produces is applied at the class level, all the methods in a resource
>   can produce the specified MIME types by default. If applied at the
>   method level, the annotation overrides any @Produces annotations
>   applied at the class level.

This would allow me to do the following:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    [RoutePrefix("subjects")]
    public class SubjectsController : Controller
    {
        [Route("{subjectId:int}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetSubject(int subjectId)
        {
        }

        [Route("{subjectId:int}")]
        [HttpGet]
        [Produces("application/pdf")]
        public ActionResult GetSubjectAsPdf(int subjectId)
        {
            //Run my custom logic here to generate a PDF.
        }
    }
}
```

There is no Produces Attribute in .NET that I can find, of course, so this doesn't work. I haven't been able to find a similar attribute, either.

I could of course manually check the header within the body of the action, and redirect it to another action, but that seems hackish at best.

**Is there a mechanism in .NET 4.5 that I may use to pull this off that I'm overlooking or missing?**

(I'm using MVC 5.2.2 from NuGet repository)

Comment: It seems to be possible using a custom controller selector: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941590/asp-net-mvc-intercepting-routing-and-forwarding-to-different-actions-routes

Comment: @mostruash Doesn't look like a controller selector is what I want, but it did get me started looking into action selectors, which are similar. I'll dig in and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: I'm now thinking that I could potentially use a route constraint on this, but I'm not sure yet.

Comment: Okay, best method for this seems to be creating an `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute`. I will post my solution soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching around the Internet for awhile, I came up with the idea that this would be best accomplished by creating an `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute`.

The following is a very naive, first-pass implementation of a `ProducesAttribute` that I wrote with the eventual intent of mimicking Java's Produces annotation:

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Mime;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public sealed class ProducesAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
    {
        private readonly ISet<ContentType> acceptableMimeTypes;

        public ProducesAttribute(params string[] acceptableMimeTypes)
        {
            this.acceptableMimeTypes = new HashSet<ContentType>();

            foreach (string acceptableMimeType in acceptableMimeTypes)
                this.acceptableMimeTypes.Add(new ContentType(acceptableMimeType));
        }

        public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo)
        {
            string acceptHeader = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept.ToString()];
            string[] headerMimeTypes = acceptHeader.Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            foreach (var headerMimeType in headerMimeTypes)
            {
                if (this.acceptableMimeTypes.Contains(new ContentType(headerMimeType)))
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

It is meant to be used with Attribute Routing, and can be applied as follows:

```
public sealed class MyController : Controller
{
    [Route("subjects/{subjectId:int}")] //My route
    [Produces("application/pdf")]
    public ActionResult GetSubjectAsPdf(int subjectId)
    {
        //Here you would return the PDF representation.
    }

    [Route("subjects/{subjectId:int}")]
    public ActionResult GetSubject(int subjectId)
    {
        //Would handle all other routes.
    }
}
```